# Reference request - first integral of vector field

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, reference-request

Let $X$ be a $C^{k}$ ($k \ge 1$) vector field on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, which means it is a differential operator:
$$X(x) := \sum_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{j}}$$
with $C^{k}$ entries $X_{1},...,X_{n}: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$. This vector field can be identified with a vector $X(x) = (X_{1}(x),...,X_{n}(x))$.

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a neighborhood of the origin. A differentiable curve $\gamma: I \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called a first integral of $X$ starting at a (fixed) $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ if $\gamma(0) = x$ and $\gamma'(t) = X(\gamma(t))$ holds for every $t \in I$.

I know there is a standard result in analysis which says that for every $C^{k}$ vector field $X$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ there exists a (unique) curve $\gamma$ which is the first integral for $X$ starting at $x$. However, I could not locate any good reference which proves this statement. Can someone please suggest a good reference in which this result is proved in details? Or even give me some hints about how to prove it?

Comment: this statement is the Picard-Lindelöf theorem on existence and uniqueness of solutions to initial value problems given some conditions. There are plenty of proofs of this theorem in internet, by example in [it wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) or [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ordinary_Differential_Equations/The_Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).